# Grapesjs - issue with Storage manager "type: 'remote'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, web-frontend, grapesjs

I am using Grapesjs version 0.16.45 and the following is my storage manager

Storage manager

```
const storageManager = useMemo(() => ({
        type: "remote",
        fromElement: false,
        id: "gjs-",
        contentTypeJson: true,
        urlStore: storeTemplate,
        headers: { ... } ,
    }), []);
```

See I run my react app in 3000 and server app in 8080 when `type: 'remote'` a request is sent to the current client URL.

In my case, a GET request is sent to `http://localhost:3000/editor/update/Znfqkl6Ho` (which is my current URL where I am using editor) and the response is `304`

Other than this everything is working fine. My `urlStore` is getting called as expected and the template is updated in the DB.

What is the issue here?

When i changed the `type` to `local` its working fine because no request will go at all. other than that i couldn't figure out the problem.